List using `tabularx` environment formatting: `\dotfill` to edge of page and space removal
I am trying to format a tabularx environment for the purposes of making a notational index (not using glossaries or index environments). Here's an MWE of my case:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Text list.}\\
\noindent symbol \indent \indent meaning of symbol \dotfill page 1.

\textbf{Tabularx list.}\\
\begin{tabularx}{1.01\textwidth}{lX<{\dotfill}r}
symbol &  meaning of symbol & page 1.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}

which has output: 
I am trying to synthesize the two lists shown. Namely, I'd like to use the tabularx environment to remove the indentation at the start of the line, and ensure that the \dotfill goes up until the page reference, removing the space added in before. I'd like to use the tabularx environment so that the alginment adapts automatically down the page as more symbols are added to the list.
Help would be very much appreciated,
M

I think they are exact same in this way:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Text list.}\\
\noindent symbol\hspace{2\tabcolsep}meaning of symbol \dotfill page 1.

\textbf{Tabularx list.}\\
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lX<{ \dotfill}@{}r@{}}
symbol &  meaning of symbol & page 1.\\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}



Thank you. This is perfect.
